# None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am doing the migration of an old Android Codebase.  I am getting the below error for the mentioned code. What could be the reason for the issue? How can we solve it easily?

```
    fun action(action: FunAction) = actor.offer(action)

    private val actor = actor<FunAction>(Dispatchers.Main, Channel.CONFLATED) {

        for (action in this) when (action) {

            is FunAction.Init -> { }

            is FunAction.SaveUserSetting -> { }

            is FunAction.UploadProfilePhoto -> { }

    }
```

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 

public fun <E> CoroutineScope.actor(context: CoroutineContext = ..., capacity: Int = ..., 
start: CoroutineStart = ..., onCompletion: CompletionHandler? /* = ((cause: Throwable?) -> Unit)? */ = ...,
block: suspend ActorScope<TypeVariable(E)>.() -> Unit): SendChannel<TypeVariable(E)> 
defined in kotlinx.coroutines.channels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the signature change for `actor` function which is now defined as an extension on `CoroutineScope`

```
public fun <E> CoroutineScope.actor(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    capacity: Int = 0, // todo: Maybe Channel.DEFAULT here?
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    onCompletion: CompletionHandler? = null,
    block: suspend ActorScope<E>.() -> Unit
): SendChannel<E>
```

So you need to call it using some scope, which scope you use that depends on use case,  from `Activity`, `Fragment` you can use `lifecycleScope` and from `ViewModel` you can use `viewModelScope` or you can use `GlobalScope` if you don't want your `coroutine` to be cancelled unless your application is killed. so the call would look like

```
yourScopeChoice.actor<FunAction>(Dispatchers.Main, Channel.CONFLATED)
```

Please note that

### `actor` function is marked by `@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi`

which means

> /**  * Marks declarations that are **obsolete** in coroutines API,
> which means that the design of the corresponding  * declarations has
> serious known flaws and they will be redesigned in the future.  *
> Roughly speaking, these declarations will be deprecated in the future
> but there is no replacement for them yet,  * so they cannot be
> deprecated right away.  */